# Как правильно использовать curl -X "Authorization: Bearer"?

Tags: php, curl

Использую следующий код для получения списка проектов пользователя через его приватный токен гитлаба:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

$headers = array();
$headers[] = "Content-Type: application/json";
$headers[] = "Accept: application/json";
$headers[] = "Authorization: Bearer [GITLAB_PRIVATE_TOKEN]";
$headers[] = "Accept-Language: en";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo $result;

if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close ($ch);
```

Но возвращается 404 ошибка, что я делаю не так?

Comment: Не удивительно, так как такого пути нет в [документации](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/api_resources.html). Если вам нужен список проектов, то добавьте /projects к URL. Так же, это должен быть [GET](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/projects.html) запрос, а не POST.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov Сделал такой запрос

 `$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$headers = array();
$headers[] = "Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8";
$headers[] = "Accept: application/json";
$headers[] = "Authorization: Bearer [TOKEN]";
$headers[] = "Accept-Language: en";

$result = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($result);

if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close ($ch);`
Но мне выводятся левые проекты, скорее всего просто недавно созданные